# how to pass data from view to model in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm developing a system with codeigniter, in my situation i have to press a link in one user interface and get it's ID and pass it to the model and get the data relevant to that ID and go to the other interface and display the data in the relevant fields, i know how to pass data from model to view, but i don't know how to pass to model from the view, can you guys please help me?

(this is my first CI project)

regards,
Rangana

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but passing data from a view to a model really isn't *usually* necessary. Maybe try explaining again. I guess I just don't know what you mean by "other interface" or "data in the relevant fields".

Comment: sorry about that, let me elaborate, i have registered patients for a day, they are registered with an ID, a doctor can login to the system and check the registered patients, when the patient arrives he click the link(registered ID) in that page to go to another page(full detail page) where patients full details are displayed, i want to pass that ID a method in the model to select those data and put it in the full detail page, this is my scenario!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass information between pages in several different ways... here's an example:

Your link: http://example.com/controller/method/id/15

```
$uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
$this->load->model('model');
$this->model->handleInput($uri['id']);
```

The above code will pass the id in the URL to the model method handleInput. Let's say your URL looks like this: http://example.com/controller/method/15 - assuming the ID segment in the URL is always in the same place, that is, after the controller and the method, you can retrieve it like this:

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->load->model('model');
$this->model->handleInput($id);
```

You can also pass data using the post method. You can retrieve safe post values using the post function, like this:

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$this->load->model('model');
$this->model->handleInput($id);
```